# NSDate returning 5 hrs 30 mts extra

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

i'm using [NSDate date] to get the current date but it is returning 5hrs 30 mts forward. it is returning different time before PM and after PM. My requirement is I want to delete the data in cache after 1 hr of duration.

At present I'm using following code to calculate the time difference.
   //storyDate is the one which is stored in cache...

```
NSTimeInterval timeGapInSeconds =fabs([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:storyDate]); 
NSInteger daysGap= timeGapInSeconds/86400;
NSInteger hoursGap = timeGapInSeconds/3600;
NSInteger mtsGap = timeGapInSeconds/60;

NSLog(@"days gap %lu, hours gap is %lu",(long)daysGap,(long)hoursGap);
NSLog(@"time gap in seconds %f",timeGapInSeconds);
 NSLog(@"time gap in mins %f",timeGapInSeconds/60);
NSLog(@"current date:%@",[NSDate date]);
```

Comment: That is due to your local time zone differing from GMT which is used when you NSLog a date

Comment: And don't use constants like 86400 for calendrical calculations (there are days with 23 or 25 hours - think of daylight saving time!). Use NSCalendar, NSDateComponents, ...

Comment: That's because you're in India.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your `dateFormatter` if you want to make it generalize  :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

Or If you are making any application for particular country then use this :

```
NSLocale *usLoc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLoc];
```

Hope this would work.